# Is there a way to select HTML <option> automatically with a javascript injection?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a form on a web page with this HTML

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    <select id="selectThis">
        <option id="one" value="1">1</option>
        <option id="two" value="2">2</option>
        <option id="three" value="3">3</option>
        <option id="four" value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <a href="gothispage.com" onclick="ajaxSubmitFunction('submit') id="submit">submit</a>
</form>
```

Is there a way to inject a js code that does basically this.

```
function selectOption(option) {
    var a = document.getElementById(option);
    a.selected = selected;
    if (a === "selected") {
        document.getElementById("submit").click();
    }
}
selectOption("four");
```

Is this the correct way of thinking about how to approach this problem?

Comment: Where has `selected` came from? Use [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Properties) to select an option prorammatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a standard way to do it, but it works. You are basically already there, you just need to tidy up some syntax:

```
function selectOption(option) {
    var a = document.getElementById(option);
    a.selected = true;
    // this if statement isn't really needed as you just set it
    if (a.selected === true) {
        document.getElementById("submit").click();
    }
}

selectOption("four");
```

[Sample JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzzwkbty/)

A more usual way to do this would be:

```
function selectOption(option) {
    var a = document.getElementById('selectThis');
    a.value = option;
    document.getElementById("submit").click();
}

selectOption("4");
```

Answer (score 1):

Get `option` element by `id` then assign it's `value` to `select` element:

```
function selectOption(option) {
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById(option).value;
    document.getElementById("selectThis").value = selectedValue;

    // ...
}

selectOption("four");
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/sewowenugu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score -1):

Try this (jQuery):


$("#selectThis").val("4");

Comment: jQuery was never mentioned in the question, though. And you'd need to explain that this answer uses it.